# Get only part of file name and delete from server folder in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying get get only the last part of a file name in a server folder between the "_" and ".pdf" in order to delete specific files only.
The files in the invoices folder are like this: Invoice_12345.pdf, Invoice_2345.pdf, Invoice_5555.pdf, etc. I need to extract the "12345", "2345", and "5555", then I need to delete the file if it is not contained in a database query.

With the following code, I wish to extract the digits from the files in the folder, so how do I get the number between "_" and ".pdf"?

```
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Contents/Invoices/"))
For Each file As String In files            
        list.Add(file)
    
Next
```

Then I need to delete the file from the server if the extracted number is not contained in a dataset I query from the database, but maybe that is a question for a different post.

```
For example, for Invoice "5555"
If PaidFull = True 
File.Delete(file)
End If
```

Of course, I would have to then get the full file name to delete if from the server at that point.

Comment: The first group of code can be a single line by adding .ToList `Dim list = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Desktop").ToList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to get only the numbers :

```
  For Each file As String In files

            Dim the_number As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)

            the_number = the_number.Substring(the_number.LastIndexOf("_") + 1, the_number.Length - the_number.LastIndexOf("_") - 1)


            list.Add(the_number )

        Next
```

Or with Regex (ty to Jimi) :

```
dim the_number = Regex.Match(file, "_(\d+)\.").Groups(1).Value
```

Comment: `the_number = the_number.Substring(the_number.LastIndexOf("_"c) + 1)`. Or `dim the_number = Regex.Match(file, "_(\d+)\.").Groups(1).Value`

Comment: I don't know much about regex but your solution seems more elegant to mine

Comment: Is this regex working with a file named like **my_file_789.78.pdf** ?

Comment: The first one yes, the second one must be tweaked, e.g., `_(.*?)\.pdf` or `_([\d|\.]*)\.`. But this is not in the parameters the OP defined.

Comment: Actually the file name is like my_file_123_12345.pdf. It's crazy how I didn't even consider that it would make a difference when I asked the question. But having different ways to accomplish the same task is awesome!

Comment: So, you wants to get the "12345" or "123_12345" ? With my solution, you get the part of the string after the position of the **last "_"**.

Comment: 12345 is what i want

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to mess with parsing the file name if you are sure the number won't pop up somewhere in the directory path.

```
    'Dim list = Directory.GetFiles("C:\SomeDirectory").ToList
    Dim myTestList As New List(Of String) From {"Invoice_12345.pdf", "Invoice_2345.pdf", "Invoice_5555.pdf"}
    For Each fileName In myTestList
        If fileName.Contains("5555") Then
            Debug.Print(fileName) 'Or do what you need to do
        End If
    Next
```